# how to change the rows attribute of <h:inputTextarea> dynamically?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a field called `ID-Text` that varies in length from 1 to 3000 words stored in a database. I want to display that in a form. Based on its size I want to vary the size of the `<h:inputTextarea>`. How can I do it.. will I be able to set row property from bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h:inputTextarea>` supports both `cols` and `rows` attributes, as you can see from the [VLD](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputTextarea.html). Example:

```
<h:inputTextarea value="#{bean.idText}" rows="#{bean.rowNrs}" cols="40" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can.., Have a look this example...

**Bean Class:**

```
private int rowValue; 

//getters & setters for rowValue    

//if you want column size as "50" then make rowValue is divided by 50.

this.rowValue = para.length()/50; //para is a string which would have database value
```

Now you have row value in back bean... just use this value as..

```
<h:inputTextarea id="para" value="#{beanName.idText}" rows="#{beanName.rowValue}" cols="50" />
```

Secondary Option..

**By JavaScript:**

You can try by using `JavaScript` like..

```
  <script language="javascript">
        function SetNewSize(textArea) {
            if (textArea.value.length > 5) {
                textArea.cols = 50;
                textArea.rows = 50;
            } else {
                textArea.cols = 30;
                textArea.rows = 20;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <textarea name="x" onKeyUp="SetNewSize(this);" cols="15" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Try similar way to implement this in your `inputTextArea`...